# Dropbox api V2, get access token in query param instead of url hash (#) (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, dropbox-api

I'm using the [official Dropbox API (V2)](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/#toc10__anchor) on my Nodejs app.
It sounds like a dumb question but I really **can't find out how to get the given access token from the callback url**. Actually, it is supposed to be in **the hash (#)** part of the url (according to their documentation and [javascript client-side exemple](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/master/examples/javascript/auth/index.html)), which is not visible by the server side...

I can't find any exemple for authentication from a nodejs app, using only the basic api.

Here is my authentication code:

My express app:

```
//Entry point, DC is a DropboxConnector object
app.get('/connect/Dropbox', function(req, res) {
   console.log('/connect/Dropbox called');
   res.redirect(DC.getConnexionURL());
});

// Callback from the authentication
app.get('/authDropbox', function(req, res) {
   console.log("/authDropbox called");
    console.log(url.format(req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl));
   // The above log is: 'http://localhost:8080/authDropbox'
   // Here is the problem, the access token is unreachable by express
   DC.getToken(req.query.code, res);
   connectorList.push(DC);
});
```

DropboxConnector.js, my dropbox api wrapper:

```
var REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:8080/authDropbox';

//The authentication url given by the dropbox api
getConnexionURL() {
    dbx = new Dropbox({ clientId: CLIENT_ID});
    var authUrl = dbx.getAuthenticationUrl(REDIRECT_URI);
    console.log("AuthURL: " + authUrl);
    return authUrl;
}

// @param code is supposed to be the access token...
getToken(code, res) {
    if (!!code) {
        dbx = new Dropbox({ accessToken: code });
        console.log("Authenticated!");
        res.redirect(CALLBACK_URL);
    } else {
        console.log("No code here");
    }
}
```

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, the contents of the fragment a.k.a. hash are not visible to the server, only the client (browser). The OAuth 2 "token" flow sends the access token on the fragment, and is mainly meant for client-side apps, e.g., JavaScript in the browser. The OAuth 2 "code" flow instead sends an authorization code as a URL parameter, for server-side apps.

If you're interested, you can find more information on the two different flows in the [Dropbox /oauth2/authorize documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-authorize).

The Dropbox API v2 JavaScript SDK unfortunately currently only supports the "token" flow, but [we're tracking this as a feature request for support for the "code" flow](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/issues/64).

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! I'll pay attention to this thread, I'll try the solution provided here (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dropbox-client-oauth2) or I'll use the http api directly instead of the javascript one, it worked quite well.

Comment: The SDK now supports the code flow. More information [here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/issues/64#issuecomment-359910107).

Comment: I've been notified by the GitHub issue post as well, but thank you for the update!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to call HTTP directly, you can use my tiny [dropbox-v2-api](https://github.com/adasq/dropbox-v2-api) wrapper package:

```
const dropboxV2Api = require(dropbox-v2-api');

const dropbox = dropboxV2Api.authenticate({
    client_id: 'APP_KEY',
    client_secret: 'APP_SECRET',
    redirect_uri: 'REDIRECT_URI'
});
//generate and visit authorization sevice 
const authUrl = dropbox.generateAuthUrl();
//after redirection, you should receive code
dropbox.getToken(code, (err, response) => {
    //you are authorized now!
});
```

Full example ([see here](https://github.com/adasq/dropbox-v2-api/blob/master/example/oauth2-flow.js)):

```
const dropboxV2Api = require(dropbox-v2-api');
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Opn = require('opn');

const credentials = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'credentials.json')));

//set auth credentials
const dropbox = dropboxV2Api.authenticate({
    client_id: credentials.APP_KEY,
    client_secret: credentials.APP_SECRET,
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:5000/oauth'
});

//prepare server & oauth2 response callback
const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 5000 });
server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/oauth',
        handler: function (request, reply) {
            var params = request.query;
            dropbox.getToken(params.code, function(err, response){
                console.log('user\'s access_token: ',response.access_token);
                //call api
                dropbox({
                    resource: 'users/get_current_account'
                }, function(err, response){
                    reply({response: response});
                });

            });                    
        }
});
server.start(function(){
    //open authorization url
    Opn(dropbox.generateAuthUrl());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at your library :)